# Matching a string between known characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've got a few thousands lines of text to get particular measurements from. The lines are always in the same format:

```
'0980 - 14'3 - Plough Yard - London EC2A 3'
'0981 - 14'3 - Waterson St - London E2 8'
'0982 - 14'3 - Union Walk - London E2 8'
'0983 - 14'3 - Union Walk - London E2 8'
'0984 - 14'3 - Hare Row - London E2 9'
'0985 - 14'3 - Sharratt St - London SE15 1'
'0986 - 14'3 - Rolt St - London SE8 5'
'0987 - 14'3 - Edward St - London SE8 5'
```

Because my knowledge of regex is so poor, the only thing I've come up with is this:

```
\-(.*?)\-
```

Which (those of you with a far greater mind for these random strings, can see) will also match on the other sides. All I need is the `14'3` part. I can't garauntee how large the numbers on the far left will get too, could get into the hundreds of thousands.

**Update**
Apparently my pattern string does work after all. The site(s) I was using to build and test it are at fault. Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: That should work so long as you apply it to one line at a time or if you're not using `dotall` (or the equivalent). What language / platform are you using?

Comment: @p.s.w.g My guess is that he doesn't want to also match `Plough Yard`, and the like

Comment: I'm not actually using any language at the moment, I'm currently on this site: http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html - With a random sample of data, attempting to do it myself. :( In the end it'll be C#

Comment: @SamIam Agreed, but it should still work as long as he's not using `dotall`: [**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C-(.*%3F)%5C-&input=%270980%20-%2014%273%20-%20Plough%20Yard%20-%20London%20EC2A%203%27%0A%270981%20-%2014%273%20-%20Waterson%20St%20-%20London%20E2%208%27%0A%270982%20-%2014%273%20-%20Union%20Walk%20-%20London%20E2%208%27%0A%270983%20-%2014%273%20-%20Union%20Walk%20-%20London%20E2%208%27%0A%270984%20-%2014%273%20-%20Hare%20Row%20-%20London%20E2%209%27%0A%270985%20-%2014%273%20-%20Sharratt%20St%20-%20London%20SE15%201%27)

Comment: @SamIam - That's correct. I only need (as stated) the measurement, i.e. the 14'3 - in the case of those above.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - What the hell?! The site I'm using matches most of the words too. Hmmm. I'll give it a shot in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to point out that your pattern works as is in the .NET regular expression engine without any other options. Here's a demonstration (I've removed the unnecessary backslashes):

```
var input = @"'0980 - 14'3 - Plough Yard - London EC2A 3'
'0981 - 14'3 - Waterson St - London E2 8'
'0982 - 14'3 - Union Walk - London E2 8'
'0983 - 14'3 - Union Walk - London E2 8'
'0984 - 14'3 - Hare Row - London E2 9'
'0985 - 14'3 - Sharratt St - London SE15 1'
'0986 - 14'3 - Rolt St - London SE8 5'
'0987 - 14'3 - Edward St - London SE8 5'";

foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(input, "-(.*?)-")) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

This is because `.` matches any character *except* newlines (unless you use ['Single-line' mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Singleline) to make it also match newlines). As long as none of the lines in your string has another `-` after `London …`, it will only match the substring between the first pair of `-`.

However, for something relatively simple like this, you can use [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) instead:

```
foreach(var line in input.Split('\n')) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(line.Split(new[] { '-' }, 3)[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex.

```
^.*?\-(.*?)\-
```

What this regex does, is it captures only the second occurence of content between `-` inside a regex group.

http://rubular.com/r/wAxtbQT4wb

Answer (score 1):

You can be very specific to very general.

This regex is fairly specific:

```
^'\d+\s+-\s+(\d\d'\d)
```

[See it work](http://regex101.com/r/wL3fQ5)

This is very general:

```
(\d+'\d+)
```

[See that work](http://regex101.com/r/mO9kO7)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
- (\d+'\d+) -
```

this will match every `14'3`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this regex also,

```
^'[0-9]+\s*-\s*([^ ]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wO8lP4)

**Explanation:**

```
    '0980 - 14'3 - Plough Yard - London EC2A 3'
   _|   |   |  |
^'[0-9]+|   |  |
_ _  _ _|   |  |_____
\s*-\s*     |  ([^ ]*)
   _ _ _ _  |_________
```